# How do I modify page tabs (content actions tab) in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I have my 1.19 Mediawiki that has page tabs look like this:
 [image]

I want to add 'Watch' link as one of the tabs which should look like this (**Watch** as the star icon instead of a text link): 
[image]

I googled around the whole morning and couldn't figure out how. It seems the latter should be the default look of Mediawiki however I just couldn't get it. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: JS-only or a PHP extension?

Comment: Search for `collapsibleNav`, there are various settings and even a JS interface

Comment: collapsibleNav is for the left hand side nav panel. but I want to modify the page tabs on upper right corner of the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer from the most obscure place on [Mediawik's manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgAjaxWatch).

set

> $wgVectorUseIconWatch

to true in your LocalSettings.php.